# fibonacci sequence induction with recurrence function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

> $$f(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{when } n = 1 \\
>                      1 & \text{when } n = 2 \\
>                      f(n-1) + f(n-2) & \text{when } n \geq 3 .
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   For any natural number $j$, show that the Fibonacci number $f(5j)$ is divisible by $5$, using mathematical induction.

So all I have is that I should probably just use $f(5j)$ and $f(5j +1)$ to get $f(5j + 5)$?

Answer (score 2):

Base case is trivial. Suppose that $f(5k)$ is divisible by $5$ for some $k \geq 1$. Then
\begin{align}
f(5(k+1)) &= f(5k + 5)\\
&= f(5k + 4) + f(5k + 3)\\
&= (f(5k + 3) + f(5k + 2)) + (f(5k + 2) + f(5k + 1))\\
&= f(5k + 3) + 2f(5k + 2) + f(5k + 1)\\
&= (f(5k + 2) + f(5k + 1)) + 2(f(5k) + f(5k + 1)) + f(5k + 1)\\
&= (2f(5k + 1) + f(5k)) + 2f(5k) + 2f(5k + 1) + f(5k + 1)\\
&= 5f(5k + 1) + 3f(5k)
\end{align}
Clearly $5|5f(5k + 1)$ and since $5 | f(5k)$ we also have $5 | 3f(5k)$ which implies that $5|(5f(5k+1) + 3f(5k)) = f(5(k+1))$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the fibonnaci numbers mod $5$. We get 
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & f(n) \mod 5 \\ \hline 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 \\ 3& 2 \\ 4 & 3 \\ 5 & 0 \\ 6 & 3 \\ 7 & 3 \\ 8 & 1 \\ 9 & 4 \\ 10  & 0
\end{array}$$

Thus we see the pattern that for $f(5j + 1) \equiv f(5 j + 2) \mod 5$, $f(5j + 3) + f(5j + 4) \equiv 0 \mod 5$ and $f(5j) \equiv 0 \mod 5$. This is easy to prove using induction.

Comment: to prove with induction do i just say f(5k+1+3) = f(5k + 1+4) = f(5k) = 0?

Comment: If $f(5j) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ then $f(5j - 1) \equiv f(5j + 1) \equiv f(5 j+ 2) \pmod 5$. Then $f(5j + 3) \equiv 2 f(5j + 2) \pmod 5$ and $f(5j + 4) \equiv 3 f(5j + 2)$ so $f(5j + 5) \equiv 5 f(5j + 2) \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Comment: i'm very bad with proofs and what not, is that basically the induction needed? I thought i have to always add a 1 to a k to get the induciton

Answer (score 0):

You can write
\begin{align}
f(n+2)&=f(n+1)+f(n)\\[6px]
f(n+3)&=f(n+2)+f(n+1)\\&=2f(n+1)+f(n)\\[6px]
f(n+4)&=f(n+3)+f(n+2)\\&=2f(n+1)+f(n)+f(n+1)+f(n)\\&=3f(n+1)+2f(n)\\[6px]
f(n+5)&=f(n+4)+f(n+3)\\&=3f(n+1)+2f(n)+2f(n+1)+f(n)\\&=5f(n+1)+3f(n)
\end{align}
Set
$$
g(j)=f(5j)
$$
You want to prove that $5\mid g(j)$.

The case $j=1$ is trivial, because $g(1)=f(5)=5$; if the statement holds for $j$, then
$$
g(j+1)=f(5(j+1))=f(5j+5)=5f(5j+1)+3f(5j)=5f(5j+1)+3g(j)
$$
and you're done.

Note that, more generally, for $k>0$,
$$
f(n+k)=f(k)f(n+1)+f(k-1)f(n)
$$
(where we use $f(0)=0$). The case $k=1$ is trivial. Then, assuming the statement holds for $k$ (and every $n$), we have
\begin{align}
f(n+k+1)&=f(n+k)+f(n-1+k)\\
&=f(k)f(n+1)+f(k-1)f(n)+f(k)f(n)+f(k-1)f(n-1)\\
&=f(k)f(n+1)+f(k)f(n)+f(k-1)f(n+1)\\
&=f(k+1)f(n+1)+f(k)f(n)
\end{align}
as required. (The case when $n=0$ is obvious, so we can assume $n>0$.)